# A complex polynomial satisfying $p(z)=p(\bar z) \forall z$ on the unit circle is constant

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

This question was part of a test on Complex Analysis.

> Let $p(z) \in \Bbb{C}$ be a complex polynomial such that $p(z)=p(\bar z) \forall z$ on the unit circle ($∣z∣=1$). Show that $p(z)$ is constant.

Now, I think the best way to approach this is via the Identity Theorem, but I have not been able to come up with the appropriate functions to make it work.
A more direct approach, that is assuming $p(z)=a_nz^n+...+a_1z+a_0={\bar a_n}{\bar z^n}+...+{\bar a_1}{\bar z}+\bar a_0$, did not help either. Any ideas?

Comment: $\overline{p(\overline z)}$ is holomorphic. So, $\overline p$ is and therefore $p+\overline p$.

Comment: "_In_ the unit circle" means _on_ or _inside_?

Comment: @quartermind "On". $∣z∣=1$ Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$
p(z)=\frac{p(z)+p(\bar{z})}{2}+\frac{p(z)-p(\bar{z})}{2}=\frac{p(z)+p(\bar{z})}{2}
$$
Hence
$$
p(z)=\sum_{k=0}^na_{k}\frac{z^k+\bar{z}^k}{2}=\sum_{k=0}^na_{k}r^k\cos{k\theta}=\sum_{k=0}^na_{k}r^k(\cos{k\theta}+i\sin{k\theta})=\sum_{k=0}^na_{k}z^k
$$
Thus for any $r<1, \theta\in[0,2\pi]$ 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^na_{k}r^k\sin{k\theta}=0
$$
We conclude that $a_k=0, \:k>1$, i.e. $p(z)$ is constant.

Comment: How did you extend $p(z) = p(\overline{z})$ to the unit disk? Note, that $p(\overline{z})$ is not holomorhic a priori.

Comment: There is no need to extend to the unit disk. $a_{k}r^k=0$ means $a_{k}=0$

Comment: But you assume $r = \lvert z \rvert < 1$, surely it means that $z$ is in the unit disk.

Comment: If $a_k=0$ for any $r<1$, then it holds on the unit disk by identity theorem.

Comment: Uh, I thought that OP has stated the problem on the circumference.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $z$ by $e^{it}$, $t \in \mathbb R$, then
$$
p(z) = f(t) = a_0 + \sum_{k=1}^n a_k (\cos kt + i \sin kt)
$$
where $a_k \in \mathbb C$.

From $p(z) = p(\overline{z})$ we obtain $f(t) = f(-t)$, and hence each coefficient of $\sin kt$ for $k \geqslant 1$ equals zero.

Comment: @hermes, what's problem? If you want to deal with real trigonometric polynomials, you can do $f(t) = g(t) + i h(t)$, where $g$ and $h$ are real. The conclusion easilly follows from its "real" analogue.

Comment: @hermes, or you can prove it directly by showing that $\sum_{k=1}^n i a_k \sin kt$ is both odd and even and using linear indepence of $\{ \sin kt \}$ over $\mathbb C$.

Comment: @hermes, I took $r = 1$ since in the OP $z$ is in the unit circle.